# How to set TCP_NODELAY on BSD socket on Solaris?

Tags: c++, c, solaris, sockets

I am trying to turn off Nagle's algorithm for a BSD socket using:

```
setsockopt(newSock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char*)&flag, sizeof flag);
```

but the compiler claims `TCP_NODELAY` hasn't been seen before:

```
error: `TCP_NODELAY' undeclared (first use this function)
```

This is the full list of includes for the file this is in:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
using namespace std;
```

I also have the `-lnsl` and `-lsocket` linker options, but it just won't compile. Am I missing something?

All of this is on a Solaris 8 machine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like you are missing `#include <netinet/tcp.h>` - that's where `TCP_...` defines live.

Comment: I tried this on Solaris 10 (I had to add it after the headers you have already included) and it worked. I got errors with including <string> - but i tried a C program, so I had to change it to <string.h>

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a Solaris box handy, only a Linux one.

```
grep -ri TCP_NODELAY /usr/include/*
```

results in:

```
/usr/include/linux/tcp.h:#define TCP_NODELAY            1       /* Turn off Nagle's algorithm. */
/usr/include/netinet/tcp.h:#define      TCP_NODELAY      1      /* Don't delay send to coalesce packets  */
```

Perhaps you could try something similar?